# Rails 4.1.1 related model attribute with nested form not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

When I submit my form to save entry, the nested value (in Ride model) named 'test' is not getting saved.

Is my entry_params method correct with respect to allowing the nested attribute through?  Is I have no ride_id value in entry record when inspecting entry object:

```
--- !ruby/object:Entry
attributes:
  id: 47
  show_date: 0008-08-08
  user_id: 
  ride_id: 
  created_at: 2014-07-04 21:08:49.294361000 Z
  updated_at: 2014-07-04 21:08:49.294361000 Z
```

I have models:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :rides, :dependent => :destroy    
  has_many :horses, :through => :rides, :dependent => :destroy    
  has_many :riders, :through => :rides, :dependent => :destroy    
end    

class Ride < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :entry    
  has_many :horses, :dependent => :destroy    
  has_many :riders, :dependent => :destroy    
end
```

my partial entry controller file:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_entry, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def new
  @entry = Entry.new
  1.times do
    @entry.rides.build
  end
end

def create
  @entry = Entry.create(entry_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @entry.save  
      format.html { redirect_to @entry, notice: 'Entry was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entry }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @entry.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
 end
end

def destroy
  @entry.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to entries_path, notice: 'Entry was successfully deleted.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end 

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_entry
    @entry = Entry.find(params[:id])
  end

  def entry_params
    params.require(:entry).permit(:show_date, ride_attributes: [:test])
  end
```

end

My form to submit entry with nested attribute:

```
<%= form_for (@entry), :url => entries_path do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :show_date %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :show_date %>
</p>
<%= f.fields_for :rides do |builder| %>  
<p>  
  <%= builder.label :test %><br>
  <%= builder.text_field :test %>
</p>
<% end %>   
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are missing **`accepts_nested_attributes_for :rides`** in your **`Entry`** model.

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :rides, :dependent => :destroy    
  has_many :horses, :through => :rides, :dependent => :destroy    
  has_many :riders, :through => :rides, :dependent => :destroy  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rides 
end
```

From the **[API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)**

> Nested attributes allow you to save attributes on associated records
>   through the parent

So,in your case the **`rides_attributes`** are not saved because you don't have **`accepts_nested_attributes_for :rides`** in your **`Entry`** model

And also your **`entry_params`** should look like this

```
def entry_params
  params.require(:entry).permit(:show_date, rides_attributes: [:test]) 
end
```

You have **`has_many :rides`**,so it should be **`rides_attributes`** not **`ride_attributes`**.

Comment: I had everything the way you described but I commented/edited to find a solution.  However, confirmation of how it should be helped me figure it out.  Thanks a lot!